# How to exclude certain files in File Mask in the 'Find in Path' function?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a bunch of typescript files which are either ended in `.ts` or `.tsx` extension. Most of them are code but some of them are storybook files and they usually have extension like `.stories.tsx`

[image]

From time to time I would like to exclude these stories book files from the search results. I tried to use a leading negative sign in File Mask (`-*.stories.ts*`, as shown in the screenshot), but it does exclude the storybook files.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not yet possible. There is a related feature request: [IDEA-104627](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104627) about the ability to use regex for specifying the file mask.

Answer (score 1):

It works. According to the corresponding [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23316/Allow-exclusion-file-name-filtering-in-Find-in-Path-dialog) it should work since 2016.

I just used the following file mask to exclude stories and tests from my tsx files: `*.tsx,!*.test.tsx,!*.stories.tsx`.